# How to hide hint label on the OutlinedTextField border

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, hint

How can I hide or disable hint label after text input?

```
OutlinedTextField(
            value = value,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
            textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = nFontSize),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
                textColor = Color.Black,
                focusedBorderColor = colorResource(id = R.color.inbox_company_red),
                cursorColor = Color.Black),
            //visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
            label = {Text(text = if (value.isEmpty()) stringResource(id = R.string.name" else "")}
```

[image]

Comment: Try using "placeholder" instead of "label"

Comment: Yes, but you need to start writing. But how can I achieve on field click?

Comment: So, you can try listening text focus state by using interactionSource. When the text has been focused, you change your placeholder state to empty string. When the focus has been lost, you change your placeholder state to initial value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide using `remember` function as this :

```
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf("")
```

Then update your `@Composable` as this :

```
OutlinedTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = {
            value = it
        },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            textColor = Color.Black,
            focusedBorderColor = Color.Red, // Change this to your desired color
            cursorColor = Color.Black
        ),
        label = {
            Text(text = if (value.isEmpty()) "Hint" else "")
        }
    )
```

Result is

[image]

[image]

### Edit

If you want to hide the `label` when gaining focus your `@Composable` you can use the `Modifier.onFocusChange` see the edited code

```
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var isFocused by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var isLabelVisible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

    OutlinedTextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = {
            value = it
        },
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(width = 200.dp, height = 100.dp)
            .onFocusChanged { focusState ->
                isFocused = focusState.isFocused
                if (focusState.isFocused) {
                    isLabelVisible = false
                } else if (value.isEmpty()) {
                    isLabelVisible = true
                }
            },
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        textStyle = TextStyle(fontSize = 16.sp),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            textColor = Color.Black,
            focusedBorderColor = Color.Red, 
            cursorColor = Color.Black
        ),
        label = {
            if (isLabelVisible) {
                Text(text = "Hint")
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: Yes, but you need to start writing. But how can I achieve on field click?

Comment: See the edit, please